# Notation in Reed/Simon Vol. IV (and possibly an earlier volume)

Tags: reference-request, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, mathematical-physics

I'm wondering if there are any mathematical physicists/analysts out there that can help me with some notation I've seen in Reed and Simon's books on analysis.  Unfortunately I don't have time to read all four volumes at the moment, and I've carefully combed through volume three (scattering) where I thought it would be defined.

> What does the symbol $(L^\infty)_\epsilon$ mean?  Presumably this is a modification on $L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^3)$ but I haven't been able to find a definition or defining property of functions in this space.

To give some context, given a Schrodinger operator $ - \Delta + V$, they'll usually define $V \in R + (L^\infty)_\epsilon$ where $R$ is a Rollnik class and proceed in a theorem from there.  Unfortunately this level of analysis is very new to me and I only need a cursory understanding of this material for a project I'm working on.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I only have volumes I and II, but both of them have a list of symbols at the back.  Does volume IV not have one, or is this symbol not in there?

Comment: @NateEldredge Volume 4 has a list of symbols in the back, and unfortunately this particular one isn't there.  I am using an older edition of the book so maybe a newer printing has an updated symbol list.

Comment: (I saw this also mentioned page 59 of Vol III without the definition, but no where else. Maybe I missed it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this notation in Simon's paper "Hamiltonians defined as quadratic forms", Commun. Math. Phys. 21 (1971), 192-210.  (PDF available on [his web page](http://math.caltech.edu/simon/biblio.html)).

A footnote at the bottom of the first page reads:

$$X + (L^\infty)_\varepsilon = \{ f \mid (\forall \varepsilon) f = x_\varepsilon + g_\varepsilon \text{ with } x_\varepsilon \in X; \|g_\varepsilon\|_\infty < \varepsilon\}.$$
So a function is in $X + (L^\infty)_\varepsilon$ iff it looks like a function from $X$ plus an arbitrarily small bounded perturbation.  As an example, Simon's footnote adds that the function $r^{-1}$ is in $L^2 + (L^\infty)_\varepsilon$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$.  (It isn't in $L^2$, but for any $\varepsilon$ you can write it as the sum of an $L^2$ function plus a bounded function of sup norm less than $\epsilon$; just cut it off outside a large ball.)

Comment: Ok great!  I guess the defining characteristic here is that for any function $f \in X + (L^\infty)_\epsilon$ you can decompose $f$ into a sum of an $X$-function and an $L^\infty$ function, say $g$ where $||g||_\infty < \epsilon$.  Presumably this gives uncountably many decompositions, depending on how small you want your $\epsilon$.